# Does TDengine support automatic table/stable creation?

Tags: sql, tdengine

Does TDengine support auto table creation mechanism? For example, I don't want to create table beforehand but data records could be inserted just using the INSERT SQL clause? If so, what are the restriction for this mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

yes，TDengine support schemaless mode, that supports create table while insert data.
TDengine support three protocal, once your data structure obey the protocal you can insert the data without create table by yourself.

More info you can refer https://tdengine.com/docs/en/v2.0/insert#schemaless

Answer (score 0):

Beside schemaless, another way is automatically create a table when inserting using SQL:

```
INSERT INTO tb_name USING stb_name TAGS (tag_value1, ...) VALUES (field_value1, ...);
```

From https://tdengine.com/docs/en/v2.0/taos-sql#insert